# SQLite Connection string unrecognized C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to SQLite database but the connection string is not recognized and gives me this error. This database file is in my project folder along with other files and for the copy option, I have "copy always" in the debug folder. The error is this:

> "valid parameters: Data Source = ..."

Code is:

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=db.sqlite;version=3;");
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Not sure if case sensitive, could you change `version` to `Version`? Does the file exist?

Comment: What SQLite library are you using? What's the NuGet package name and version?

Comment: @Max I changed it but still the same error. This error is shown in the catch part of the code.
EDIT: I'm getting another error when I changed version to Version. An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in SQLite.NET.dll

Comment: @mason I'm using Finisar.SQLite namespace and I added the .dll in the projects' references. It's version is 3.

Comment: Why are you manually referencing DLL's? Use NuGet. And why not use the most popular SQLite package available? https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=sqlite

Comment: I followed a tutorial and they referenced that manually as I'm new to this. Okay I'll try installing it from NuGet.

Comment: If a tutorial you're following recommends manually referencing a DLL, then the tutorial is either very old or very bad. I'd really think twice about learning from something that's so out of touch with modern practices.

Comment: Okay thanks for your suggestion, I'm installing it now and I'll see if that error persists. Can you tell me where should I put .sqlite file if I want it to be executable with the application so that anyone who uses it will still be able to access the database and modify it?

Comment: @User005 just my two cents here, in ASP.NET Core I had to remove the version argument

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\db.sqlite;Version=3;");
```

Specify the location of the database in the drive.